# Not loading bootstrap cdn in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Laravel 5.6 and in my blade view, I have bootstrap CDN to load bootstrap.

**Blade file :**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>pie chart</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
            .box{
                width: 600px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3 align="center">Category Chart</h3>
        <br>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-heading">Percentage of Categoryies</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="pie_chart" style="width:750px; height: 450px;">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

But not loading bootstap.

How to fix this?

Comment: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.css` gives an `AccessDenied` error, which is probably significant.

Comment: According to https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/, they now use stackpath instead of maxcdn.

Comment: They still use `maxcdn` check the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just got a wrong link to the bootstrap framework CSS, you need to add a missing `css` part to the link :

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/bootstrap.min.css
_______________________________________________^ HERE
```

Should be :

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
________________________________________________^^^
```

Check the Bootstrap CDN section in the **[official documentation](https://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.6/docs/getting-started/#download-cdn)**.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>pie chart</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    .box {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3 align="center">Category Chart</h3>
    <br>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-heading">Percentage of Categoryies</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="pie_chart" style="width:750px; height: 450px;">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```